# Import XML in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: xml, windows, import, task, scheduled-tasks

I have created a task in Windows Task Scheduler which I would like to import into another machine. I am using the command below, but I am getting an error, wondering if someone could help, thanks.

schtasks.exe /create /tn MyTask /xml "C:\tmp\exported_task.xml" /f

ERROR: The user name or password is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, you need to specify the credentials under which account the task will be created for. The syntax should be similar to the below,

schtasks.exe /create /tn MyTask /xml "C:\tmp\exported_task.xml" /ru %COMPUTERNAME%\my_user /rp my_pass